# How to sync an IBM Netezza table with a Power BI dataset

Tags: sharepoint, powerbi, ibm-cloud, power-automate, netezza

I'm using a Power BI report to display a chart based on a dataset that is extracted from a Netezza database. I used the odbc connector to extract the data from Netezza to Power BI and then used it for my chart. However the table that I used is often updated as new records are added every month. That's why I'm trying to find a way to link my Power BI dataset to my Netezza table so that when the table is udpated so is my datatset and therefore my chart.

I tried to use Power Automate however after a lot of research I found that there is no way to create a dataflow from an netezza table. Unfortunately, Power automate is the only free alternative that I know that could help me for my problem. So if anyone knows another way to do this (that doesn't cost money) with or without Power automate I would really appreciate it.

Ps: Sorry if there's any grammatical/spelling errors, I'm not a native english speaker.